# My, we are a talkative bunch. Should our comments be so chatty?

Tags: discussion, comments

I've noticed that many of our answers are getting comments akin to "Thanks! This is a great recommendation!" or simply chatter

On other SE sites, this type of comment - one that isn't adding more than a 'thank you' - would be flagged as to chatty. Should we be doing that here, or should we take these are more explicit "I agree with this" endorsements?

I think if the comment is just saying "Thank you", it should be removed. The upvote is how you add your endorsement. If, however, you want to add some other information, then the comment is acceptable.

Below is a small sampling that I found while writing up this question:

- [Looks great ;).](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/341/cheap-usb3-0-hub#comment684_345)
- [I know! It's like the fashion statement for USB hubs :P](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/341/cheap-usb3-0-hub#comment692_345)
- [Wow...thank you for pointing that out to me. *face palm*](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/123/1tb-or-more-hdd-for-playstation-4#comment258_123)
- ["multiple boyfriends/girlfriends', really :D? What if you just want to separate your business and private calls?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/256/mobile-phone-used-only-for-calls-sms#comment671_337)
- [Thak you for the recommendations. Kindle seems like a nice bet. I would like to wait some more time for more nice answers, before accepting one.](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/260/what-is-a-good-light-weight-ebook-reader#comment548_264)
- [Darn it! This is exactly what I was going to recommend... Ah, oh well :)](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/298/what-are-some-good-mobile-credit-card-readers#comment633_299)

I don't want to squash the friendly atmosphere, but I do want a bit of clarification on how much chatter we want in the comments.

Comment: Definitely shouldn't be flagging these until we get our own moderators, there's no reason to waste CM time handling these when we'll be able to delete them on our own in a few weeks. Egregious cases, where the thread has exploded, yes, but not all of them.

Answer (score 6):

*Thank you*-type comments are nice to see, both for the poster that their work has been recognised, and for the community that we're a friendly bunch. However, their useful lifespan is incredibly short.

The general advice given about comments is that they're *second-class citizens*. (Poor comments.) If something looks like it's outlived its usefulness, it may well get deleted. If you think it *should* be deleted, flag it so that mods can take a look - while we don't have any *right now*, we'll be getting them when we go public.

On commenting in general: comment what you like. However, if it doesn't add useful pertinent information to the post, don't expect it to stick around forever - and even for comments that do, that information can be edited in and the comment removed.

That said, I don't want to impede the friendly atmosphere we've got around here - so do keep being friendly, just don't get too upset if something gets removed.

Comment: We need a new suggestion. The *countdown* comment: comments that self-delete after a period of time has passed.

Comment: @Pacerier mod-flag them with a note to delete them after X time.